# React Typescript Context usage issue - "Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined'."

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have the following context code:

```
export type StoreDataContextType = {
  selectedItem: Hit<Record<any, any>> | null;
};
const initialState: StoreDataContextType = {
  selectedItem: null,
};
export const ItemContext = createContext(initialState);

type UpdateSelectedItemAction = {
  type: "UPDATE_SELECTED_ITEM";
  payload: {
    selectedItem: Hit<Record<any, any>>;
  };
};

type Action = UpdateSelectedItemAction; // add more actions here

export const ItemDispatchContext = createContext<
  React.Dispatch<Action> | undefined
>(undefined);

function itemReducer(
  state: StoreDataContextType,
  action: Action
): StoreDataContextType {
  ... reducer code here
}

export const ItemContextProvider: FC = ({ children }) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(itemReducer, initialState);

  return (
    <ItemContext.Provider value={state}>
      <ItemDispatchContext.Provider value={dispatch}>
        {children}
      </ItemDispatchContext.Provider>
    </ItemContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

The issue is that when I'm using my context in a component I get the following error:

```
TS2722: Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined'.

export const ItemCol = ({ hit: item }: Props) => {
  const dispatch = useContext(ItemDispatchContext);

  function onItemClick() {
    dispatch({ type: "UPDATE_SELECTED_ITEM", payload: { selectedItem: item } });
  }
```

Question - How I can prevent getting the error above without adding the following code every time I'm using dispatch?

```
if ( dispatch) {... }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way you can accomplish this is to provide a placeholder function to the initial context that clearly shows its a problem if used.

```js
export const ItemDispatchContext = createContext<React.Dispatch<Action>>(() => {
        console.error("Default dispatch used. You are probably using this context without the Provider.");
    } as React.Dispatch<Action>
);
```

This allows the `undefined` type to be removed (which is causing the problem you're describing), but should hopefully give a clear enough message in a bug situation.